# regex throws StackOverFlow Error

Tags: java, regex

I have a simple regexp question.  I have the following multiline string:

```
description: line1\r\nline2\r\n...
```

And I am trying to find all the lines that come after the `description:`.  I used the following regexp (and few more):

```
description: ((.*\r\n){1,})
```

...without any success.  Then I found that there is a 'Regexp StackOverflow' bug (stated as won't fix) in Sun, see [Bug #5050507](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5050507).  Can anyone please provide me with the magic formula to overcome this annoying bug?  Please note that the total length of the lines must exceed 818 bytes!!

Comment: Try `description:\s((?:[^\r\n]*+\r\n)++)`

Answer (score 1):

Since you are matching anything beyond the text `description`, you can simply allow the dot to match newlines with `Pattern.DOTALL`:

```
description:\s(.*)
```

So, in Java:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("description:\\s(.*)", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
    ResultString = regexMatcher.group(1);
}
```

The only semantic difference to your regex (apart from the facts that it won't blow your stack) is that it would also match if whatever follows after `description:` does not contain a newline. Also, your regex will not match the last line of the file unless it ends in a newline, mine will. Which behaviour is preferable is your decision.

Of course, your functionality could be emulated like this:

```
description:\s(.*\r\n)
```

but I doubt that that's really what you want. Or is it?

Comment: I think the OP took that "818" number from the bug report he cited--i.e., he's just saying the strings he's working with will always be long enough to trigger this behavior.

Comment: @Alan Moore: Oh, OK. That wasn't clear at all from his question, though :)

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the error:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
{
    sb.append("j\r\n");
}
String s = "description: " + sb.toString(); 
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("description: ((.*\r\n){1,})");
//Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("description: ((?:.*\r\n)++)");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
boolean b = matcher.find();
if (b) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

The quantifier `{1,}`is the same as `+` so you should use `+` instead, but this still fails. To fix it you can (as Bat K. points out) change the `+` to `++` making it possessive, which disables backtracking, preventing the stack overflow.